# Square of an increasing function over an interval.

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f:I\rightarrow R$ be an increasing function where **I** is an interval in **R**.Then

(a) $f^2$ is always increasing

(b) $f^2$ is always decreasing

(c)$f^2$ is constant$\Rightarrow  f$ is constant

(d)) $f^2$ may be neither increasing nor decreasing.

**My try**

If we take $I:[-1,1]$ and $f(x)=x$ then option (a) and (b) will be wrong.

For option (c). Let$ f^2(x)=k$ then $f(x)= \sqrt k  \  \ or -  \sqrt k$. So **(c)** may be write.

**But the correct answer is option (a)**

Can anyone explain.
This question was asked in entrance exam.Please see this image[image]

Comment: Note that to rule out option (c), you can use this counterexample:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}-\sqrt{k} & -1\leq x<0\\\sqrt{k} & 0\leq x\leq 1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Your solution key is wrong and the correct option is (d). Also you have rejected (a), (b) correctly. Mathematics books are not always correct especially in terms of printing answers. The image which you have given in your question is not even from a textbook. Such printed material from various coaching institutions should not be relied for knowledge rather they are a source of good questions for preparation.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh delhi university msc entrance exam gave its answer (a) in its official key

Comment: I feel sorry for the examiner then. They are human and can make mistakes. Perhaps it's a typo or may be the question was for functions $I\to\mathbb {R} ^{+} $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh if I to R^+ then what will be its answer?

Comment: You can have a look at the classic case for a question from a more prestigious exam in my [blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2010/08/two-problems-from-iit-jee.html).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  Sorry I want to clear one thing. In place of$I$ there should be $R^+$ . Then its answer is (a)

Comment: @ParamanandSingh if yes then how can we prove f is always increasing. Because the  below soln assumed that f is differentiable

Answer (score 3):

I am converting my comments into an answer and comments will be deleted shortly.

---

For the given question the correct answer is (d) (you have already rejected (a), (b) via a correct argument and one of the comments to the question rejects (c)). So either there is a typo in question or in official key. Such printing mistakes are reasonable and in any case not a punishable offence :) :)

If on the other hand the question is about a function $f:I\to\mathbb{R} ^{+} $ which is increasing then it should be obvious that the correct answer is (a). This is because if $f$ is increasing then for any $x, y\in I$ with $x<y$ we have $f(x) \leq f(y) $ and since $f(x), f(y) $ are positive it follows that $f^{2}(x)\leq f^{2}(y)$ and thus $f^2$ is increasing. One can easily prove that the option (c) also holds.

Moreover one should notice that the ideas of increasing / decreasing functions does not necessarily require the functions concerned to be differentiable. And therefore it is not necessary to invoke any arguments based on derivatives to solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you for efforts

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora: the pleasure is all mine. BTW you have come to the right online forum for any mathematical help. In case you are busy with preparation for any entrance exam, best of luck to you!

Comment: sorry . Your answer needs a little correction if you take $f:I/rightarrow R^+$ then both $a$ and $c$ will be correct.

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora: if multiple correct options are allowed then (c) is also correct.